# Best way to hydrate/populate a complex object's properties for data transfer

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

Looking for suggestions to increase load performance.  I have a complex object with multiple properties which ultimately gets serialize to XML/JSON for data transfer.  Some of the properties are also collections of data types (`List<T>`) such as "desks" for which a user belongs to for example.  The data which eventually populate these properties live in different database tables etc.  I currently implement Lazy load for getting/setting these properties.  What other design and data access patterns would make this faster?

Example:

```
    class MyDao
    {
         public int? uid { get; set; }
         public string p1 {get;set;}
         private Lazy<IEnumerable<string>> _desks;

         public IEnumerable<string> desks 
         {
              get { return _desk.Value; }
         }

         // More properties implemented via lazy...

         public MyDao(int? id, string prop1)
         {
              uid = id;
              p1 = prop1;
         }

         public void SetDesks(Func<int?,IEnumerable<string>> getDesk)
         {
              _desk = new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(() => getDesk(uid));
         }

    }

    // Initialize
    var dao = new MyDao(1,"something");
   dao.SetDesk(MyDaoHelper.GetDesk);

   // get desks
   foreach(var desk in dao.desks){
   //..do something with desk
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network => http://codereview.stackexchange.com